# Non-isomorphic connected bipartite simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How many non-isomorphic connected bipartite simple graphs are there with four vertices?

I got below 3.

[image]

Numerically my answer is valid. But is it logically valid?

Comment: What was your logic? You've not written how you reached here

Comment: Looks correct if you don't care about which named node has which 'function'. For example, in your left example, there are 3 more isomorphic versions were B, C, and D take the 'central place' that A has in your example. Those are isomorphic, but depending on why you need to consider this problem, those might still count as different. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula, which deals with 'labeled' trees, which is obviously different from the question of unlabled trees.